# CheckedListBox don't check on item selection

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a WinForms `CheckedListBox` and when I click on an item, it checks it in the list (I have `CheckOnClick` set to `True`). I want to change it so that the user must *explicitly* click the checkbox in order to check that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, misread ur question check the below link instead

[CheckedListBox Control - Only checking the checkbox when the actual checkbox is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093961/checkedlistbox-control-only-checking-the-checkbox-when-the-actual-checkbox-is)

Comment: Thanks, marked mine as a duplicate (couldn't find that other answer before)

Comment: You are welcomed :)